# Saving a json file to the computer using The request module

Tags: javascript, json, api, https, request

I am an amateur in coding, so seeking help here. I am trying to request data from RescueTime using the Request module. 
-I have figured out how to get the Body of the data but couldn't find a way to write/save the JSON file to the local hard disk. Here's the JS snippet

```
var request = require("request");

request({ uri: "https://www.rescuetime.com/anapi/daily_summary_feed?key=MY_API_KEY", method: "GET" }, function(error, response, body) {
  var jsonfile = require('jsonfile')

  var file = '/Documents/request-playground/data.json'
  //Path on the local hard disk

  var obj = {name: 'JP'}

  jsonfile.writeFile(body, obj, {spaces: 2}, function(err) {
    console.error(err)
  })

});
```

Comment: look at the `fs` module

Comment: `Here's the JS snippet` - damn that's hard to read ... use a code block (`{}` in the editor menu)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just copied the example from the npm page. If you want to write to `file` you need to make that the first parameter to `writeFile`. In the example the payload written to the file is `obj`, here it should be `body`.

This should do the trick for you:

```
var request = require("request");
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile');

request("https://www.rescuetime.com/anapi/daily_summary_feed?key=MY_API_KEY", function(error, response, body) {


  var file = '/Documents/request-playground/data.json'
  //Path on the local hard disk

  jsonfile.writeFile(file, body, {spaces: 2}, function(err) {
    console.error(err)
  })

});
```